# Javascript: create DOM element that is defined in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

In my .jsp file I have the defined a list like this:

```
<script type="text" id="my_list">
    <ol class="a-ordered-list a-vertical a-spacing-medium"></ol>
</script>
```

I want to create such list (with this exact css defined here) in Javascript, dynamically, when I need it. Like this:

```
function updateData(data, cell, $) {
    var list = document.createElement($("#my_list").html());
    // ...
```

However this results in:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided

```
('
        <ol class="a-ordered-list a-vertical a-spacing-medium"></ol>
    ')
```

is not a valid name.

How to achieve this? How to dynamically create in JS a predefined element from HTML?

Comment: See the documentation for `createElement()`.  It takes tag name.

Comment: It sounds like you're actually looking for clone.

Comment: @SLaks I think IE does (or used to) accept markup like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery:

```
var list = $($("#my_list").html());
```

You can then use jQuery APIs to append that to the DOM (for example):

```
$("#something").append(list);
```

The `document.createElement()` API expects just a tag name, so passing in the complete markup is what's causing your error. The markup is OK however for jQuery, which uses a different approach to building the new DOM node(s).